# QML List View Drag and Drop

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to create two qml list views that can perform two functions:

1. Drag and drop items within one list to change order of items
2. Drag and drop items cross lists. Items will remove from one list and add to another

Based on the Drag and Drop example in Qt Documentation, I decided to create two list views that accessing the same list model. Each item in the list model has a key as a bool value. Using DelegateModel with a filter, I can display items with key equals to true in one list and with false in the second list. When dragging an item from first list to second list, the key value will be flipped.
Now, I am facing two problems:

- onDropped is not executed
- DelegateModel is not refreshed after key value changed

Can anybody help me solve these problems or maybe have a better solution?

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("List View Test")

    property bool dropAreaOneEntered: false
    property bool dropAreaTwoEntered: false
    property int listNumer: 0

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        ListView {
            id: displayListOne
            width: 100; height: parent.height
            model: displayListOneModel

            property int dragItemIndex: -1

            moveDisplaced: Transition {
                NumberAnimation{
                    properties: "x,y"
                    duration: 200
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: displayListTwo
            width: 100; height: parent.height
            anchors.right: parent.right
            model: displayListTwoModel

            property int dragItemIndex: -1

            moveDisplaced: Transition {
                NumberAnimation{
                    properties: "x,y"
                    duration: 200
                }
            }
        }

        // ..........................................................

        ListModel {
            id: itemsListModel
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "blue"; key: true }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "orange"; key: false }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "blue"; key: true }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "orange"; key: false }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "blue"; key: true }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "orange"; key: false }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "blue"; key: true }
            // @disable-check M16
            ListElement { colore: "orange"; key: false }
        }

        // ..........................................................

        DelegateModel {
            id: displayListOneModel

            model: itemsListModel
            delegate: MouseArea {
                id: mouseOneArea
                width: 100; height: 100

                property bool held: false

                drag.target: held ? itemOneBlock : undefined
                drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis

                property var draggedItem: null

                onPressAndHold: {
                    held = true
                    listNumer = 1
                    displayListOne.dragItemIndex = index
                }
                onReleased: {
                    listNumer = 0
                    held = false
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: itemOneBlock
                    anchors { horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter; verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter }
                    width: 100
                    height: 100

                    color: colore
                    opacity: mouseOneArea.held ? 0.8 : 1.0

                    Drag.active: mouseOneArea.held
                    Drag.source: mouseOneArea
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2

                    states: State{
                        when: mouseOneArea.held
                        ParentChange { target: itemOneBlock; parent: root }
                        AnchorChanges {
                            target: itemOneBlock
                            anchors { horizontalCenter: undefined; verticalCenter: undefined }
                        }
                    }
                }

                DropArea {
                    id: listOneDropArea
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    property bool flag: false

                    onExited: dropAreaOneEntered = false
                    onEntered: {
                        dropAreaOneEntered = true
                        if (dropAreaOneEntered & ! dropAreaTwoEntered){
                            if (listNumer == 1){
                                displayListOneModel.items.move(drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex,
                                                               mouseOneArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    onDropped: {
                        console.log("onDropped has been executed!")
                    }
                }
            }

            groups: [
                DelegateModelGroup {
                    includeByDefault: true
                    name: "listOne"
                }
            ]

            filterOnGroup: "listOne"

            Component.onCompleted: {
                var rowCount = itemsListModel.count;
                for( var i = 0; i < items.count; i++ ) {
                    var entry = items.get(i).model;
                    if((entry.key != true)) {
                        items.removeGroups(i,1,"listOne")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DelegateModel {
            id: displayListTwoModel

            model: itemsListModel
            delegate: MouseArea {
                id: mouseTwoArea
                width: 100; height: 100

                property bool held: false

                drag.target: held ? itemTwoBlock : undefined
                drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis

                onPressAndHold: {
                    held = true
                    listNumer = 2
                    displayListTwo.dragItemIndex = index
                    console.log("current index is "+index)
                }
                onReleased: {
                    listNumer = 0
                    held = false
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: itemTwoBlock
                    anchors { horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter; verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter }
                    width: 100
                    height: 100

                    color: colore
                    opacity: mouseTwoArea.held ? 0.8 : 1.0

                    Drag.active: mouseTwoArea.held
                    Drag.source: mouseTwoArea
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2

                    states: State{
                        when: mouseTwoArea.held
                        ParentChange { target: itemTwoBlock; parent: root }
                        AnchorChanges {
                            target: itemTwoBlock
                            anchors { horizontalCenter: undefined; verticalCenter: undefined }
                        }
                    }
                }

                DropArea {
                    id: listTwoDropArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onExited: dropAreaTwoEntered = false
                    onEntered: {
                        dropAreaTwoEntered = true
                        if (dropAreaTwoEntered & ! dropAreaOneEntered){
                            if (listNumer == 2){
                                displayListTwoModel.items.move(drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex,
                                                               mouseTwoArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    onDropped: {
                        console.log("Flip the key value here!")
                    }
                }
            }

            groups: [
                DelegateModelGroup {
                    includeByDefault: true
                    name: "listTwo"
                }
            ]
            filterOnGroup: "listTwo"
            Component.onCompleted: {
                var rowCount = itemsListModel.count;
                for( var i = 0; i < items.count; i++ ) {
                    var entry = items.get(i).model;
                    if((entry.key != false)) {
                        items.removeGroups(i,1,"listTwo")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```