# How to rearrange a QML list via drag-and-drop

Tags: listview, qml, tableview, qt-creator

Is there a functionality to rearrange items within a QML list view (listview, tableview, or otherwise)? This question was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754226/qml-list-view-drag-and-drop) without an answer.

I followed the [Qt Tutorial on Dynamic View Ordering](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html) which, initially, did not compile in Qt-5.9, as it did not recognize the ListModel. I also tried [this tutorial](http://blogofmu.com/2011/04/18/drag-and-drop-reorder-list-in-qml-qt/) which created the view below, but does not rearrange; rather, the entire screen moves like one single Swipe View. I'm not sure if this worked in older versions of Qt and is now disfunctional?

The entire code source can be found [here](http://blogofmu.com/2011/04/18/drag-and-drop-reorder-list-in-qml-qt/). I'll post the drag-and-drop functionality below:

```
MouseArea {
    id: dragArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    property int positionStarted: 0
    property int positionEnded: 0
    property int positionsMoved: Math.floor((positionEnded - positionStarted)/starwarsNumberText.height)
    property int newPosition: index + positionsMoved
    property bool held: false
    drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
    onPressAndHold: {
        starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 2,
        positionStarted = starwarsDelegateBorder.y,
        dragArea.drag.target = starwarsDelegateBorder,
        starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 0.5,
        starwarsList.interactive = false,
        held = true
        drag.maximumY = (wholeBody.height - starwarsNumberText.height - 1 + starwarsList.contentY),
        drag.minimumY = 0
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        positionEnded = starwarsDelegateBorder.y;
    }
    onReleased: {
        if (Math.abs(positionsMoved) < 1 && held == true) {
            starwarsDelegateBorder.y = positionStarted,
            starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
            starwarsList.interactive = true,
            dragArea.drag.target = null,
            held = false
        } else {
            if (held == true) {
                if (newPosition < 1) {
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 1,
                    starwarsModel.move(index,0,1),
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
                    starwarsList.interactive = true,
                    dragArea.drag.target = null,
                    held = false
                } else if (newPosition > starwarsList.count - 1) {
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 1,
                    starwarsModel.move(index,starwarsList.count - 1,1),
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
                    starwarsList.interactive = true,
                    dragArea.drag.target = null,
                    held = false
                }
                else {
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 1,
                    starwarsModel.move(index,newPosition,1),
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
                    starwarsList.interactive = true,
                    dragArea.drag.target = null,
                    held = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: wholeBody
        width: 360
        height: 360
        ListModel {
            id: starwarsModel
            ListElement {
                number: "IV"
                title: "A New Hope"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "V"
                title: "The Empire Strikes Back"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "VI"
                title: "Return of the Jedi"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "I"
                title: "The Phantom Menace"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "II"
                title: "Attack of the Clones"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "III"
                title: "Revenge of the Sith"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "VII"
                title: "The Force of the Jedi"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "VIII"
                title: "The New Republic Challenged"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "IX"
                title: "The Force Combined"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "X"
                title: "The Council Rebuilt"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "XI"
                title: "Jedi Outnumbered"
            }
            ListElement {
                number: "XII"
                title: "The Ultimate Force"
            }
        }
        Component {
            id: starwarsDelegate
            Rectangle {
                id: starwarsDelegateBorder
                border.color: "black"
                width: wholeBody.width
                height: starwarsNumberText.height
                Row {
                    spacing: 10
                    Text { id: starwarsNumberText; text: number }
                    Text { text: title }
                    Text { text: index }
                }
MouseArea {
    id: dragArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    property int positionStarted: 0
    property int positionEnded: 0
    property int positionsMoved: Math.floor((positionEnded - positionStarted)/starwarsNumberText.height)
    property int newPosition: index + positionsMoved
    property bool held: false
    drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
    onPressAndHold: {
        starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 2,
        positionStarted = starwarsDelegateBorder.y,
        dragArea.drag.target = starwarsDelegateBorder,
        starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 0.5,
        starwarsList.interactive = false,
        held = true
        drag.maximumY = (wholeBody.height - starwarsNumberText.height - 1 + starwarsList.contentY),
        drag.minimumY = 0
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        positionEnded = starwarsDelegateBorder.y;
    }
    onReleased: {
        if (Math.abs(positionsMoved) < 1 && held == true) {
            starwarsDelegateBorder.y = positionStarted,
            starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
            starwarsList.interactive = true,
            dragArea.drag.target = null,
            held = false
        } else {
            if (held == true) {
                if (newPosition < 1) {
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 1,
                    starwarsModel.move(index,0,1),
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
                    starwarsList.interactive = true,
                    dragArea.drag.target = null,
                    held = false
                } else if (newPosition > starwarsList.count - 1) {
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 1,
                    starwarsModel.move(index,starwarsList.count - 1,1),
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
                    starwarsList.interactive = true,
                    dragArea.drag.target = null,
                    held = false
                }
                else {
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.z = 1,
                    starwarsModel.move(index,newPosition,1),
                    starwarsDelegateBorder.opacity = 1,
                    starwarsList.interactive = true,
                    dragArea.drag.target = null,
                    held = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: starwarsList
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: starwarsModel
            delegate: starwarsDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no `ListView` in the provided code. Please post [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @folibis MRE added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my issue - the above example is indeed correct as-is. However, on my machine my implementation was taking a *very* long time to initiate the `pressAndHold` action of the MouseArea. I solved it by changing to `pressed`.

Comment: This behavior could fail on touch pads. `pressAndHold` delay could be decreased - `pressAndHoldInterval` property.

Comment: in your main function, you can set the interval if press and hold like follows: app.styleHints()->setMousePressAndHoldInterval(100); where app is your QGuiApplication